# Page.cs clases to App.cs clases

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have faced a problem, i created a class on App.cs:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

And a public variable:

```
public Article ToArticlePage { get; set; }
```

And on NewsPage i have the same class article:

```
public class Article
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public long Date { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("author")]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("imageURL")]
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

Then i'm trying to do this:

On selection change i'm parsing articles ID, and in a list of articles ( NewsList ) i'm finding it. And giving it to a global variable ToArticlePage.

```
   private void NewsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NLBI = (NewsListBoxItem)NewsListBox.SelectedItem;
        Predicate <Article> articleFinder = (Article p) => { return p.Id == int.Parse(NLBI.id.Text); };
        (App.Current as App).ToArticlePage = NewsList.Result.Articles.Find(articleFinder);
    }
```

Errors:

```
Error   7   Cannot convert type 'WP8Release2.NotAuthorizedPages.HomePage.Article' to 'WP8Release2.Article'  C:\Users\4\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WP8Release2\WP8Release2\NotAuthorizedPages\HomePage.xaml.cs    348 50  WP8Release2

Error   12  Cannot implicitly convert type 'WP8Release2.NotAuthorizedPages.HomePage.Article' to 'WP8Release2.Article'   C:\Users\4\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WP8Release2\WP8Release2\NotAuthorizedPages\HomePage.xaml.cs    348 50  WP8Release2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create an an [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (at the top of your cs file)

```
using HPArticle = WP8Release2.NotAuthorizedPages.HomePage.Article;
```

then in your program you call this type of article via

```
private void NewsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NLBI = (NewsListBoxItem)NewsListBox.SelectedItem;
    Predicate <HPArticle> articleFinder = (HPArticle p) => { return p.Id == int.Parse(NLBI.id.Text); };
    (App.Current as App).ToArticlePage = NewsList.Result.Articles.Find(articleFinder);
}
```

---

Otherwise you need to include the full path wherever you use it `(WP8Release2.NotAuthorizedPages.HomePage.Article)`

The error you are getting is saying there is two different types of `Article` being used in your class, and it doesn't know which one you want to use